# Input & near features fields into the point distance table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, point, distance

wondering in ArcGIS 10.3x how can I carry-over the fields in the "Input Features" and "Near Features" layer to the point distance table? The point distance table only lists the Input_FID, Near_FID, Distance.
[image]

In above, the point distance table only has FID and distance but the "subs" and "lld" fields are missing...

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a join or relate or [query table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-query-table.htm). It's unclear from your question which one you want, so I would read up [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/about-joining-and-relating-tables.htm).
For example, for the join, you would join the near table's FID to your LikeptA's FID to show up in the same table, however if it's a one to many relationship you may want to look into a relate or query table.

Comment: I made a model that imports the input .dbf files into a .gdb, creates XY event layers, outputs point feature layers, Point Distance analysis and outputs a .dbf with Input_FID records and Near_FID records joined to the PointDistance.dbf. My model runs for a long time and the two joins take 1 hour 38 minutes and 1 hour and 45 minutes. The input tables have 6,454 records and the Point Distance table has 494,260 records, so obviously its lot of join. How can I make this slightly faster? Here's model Python script: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2FwVMYY-U-fak9aUEpadGNmdjQ?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you should create a separate question for this, on first look - I really don't understand your definition of your variables in the first 5 lines.

Comment: Thanks GISKid for your 2 comments and I'll try to clarify it better.